# Will I overwrite or append existing form field validators with registerClientValidators?

Tags: 2013, list-form, client-side-rendering

I am a bit confused with the right way of registering custom CSR callbacks for fields on a list form.

While things are pretty straightforward if I am developing a totally custom field control, I am not so sure about the right way of "subclassing" standard SharePoint controls.

For example, it seems that if I call the standard SPFieldNote_Edit function in my control template and then register a custom init callback, the init callback previously registered by SPFieldNode_Edit will be overwritten, effectively breaking the normal operation of the standard control.

Neither am I sure about custom validators: if I invoke a standard control template and then call registerClientValidators, will the standard validators be overwritten with my ClientValidatorSet, or will rather my ClientValidatorSet will be appended to the list?

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything specific in the documentation, and neither there seems to be an Office PnP sample demonstrating proper *subclassing* of the standard controls.

Perhaps I could find the answers by looking at the internals of clienttemplates.js, but I am not sure if I am supposed to look there (legally, at least).

So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only done custom validation through CSR once, and aside from my actual custom validation logic, it was based heavily on the code in [this example by Martin Hatch](https://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1-overview-url-tokens-and-applying-jslink-to-objects.html). Based on what's happening in that code, here are my suspicions.

I would say that if you use `registerClientValidator`, you will be **overwriting** any existing validators for that field.  Why do I suspect that?

First of all, in the example code, he starts with new-ing up a new `ValidatorSet` object:

```
// register the field validators
var fieldValidators = new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.ValidatorSet();
```

which ultimately gets registered for the field.  Secondly, he checks to see if the field is required, and if so, adds a required field validator:

```
if (formCtx.fieldSchema.Required) {
  fieldValidators.RegisterValidator(
    new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.RequiredValidator()
  );
}
```

Then he adds his custom validator, and finally registers the validator set with the field in the form:

```
formCtx.registerClientValidator(formCtx.fieldName, fieldValidators);
```

If `registerClientValidator` *appended* the validators to any existing ones, why bother checking if the field is required and adding a required field validator?

So my suspicion is that if you use `formCtx.registerClientValidator` you will be replacing any previously registered validator set.

However, that begs the question, can you somehow retrieve an existing validator set that has been registered for a field, and just append new validators into the existing set?  Clearly `fieldValidators.RegisterValidator`, the way it is used in the example code, is an appending function.

A lot of "unofficial" but highly accurate and useful documentation about how CSR works has come from poring over `clienttemplates.debug.js`, so that seems like it might be the way to go to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Excellent! In the foreseeable future, I will hardly need anything beyond the basic required validator from the stock SharePoint code, so your example has anything I need to know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's all good except for the part where it overrides. In fact, when you register a ValidatorSet you can see SharePoint code calls MergeValidators if there are already existing ones.

The reason you might need to register the requried validator is if you created a "custom" field rendering, then there are no built-in ones automatically. But if you just want to add another validator to a regular text box (say: validate as email) you won't have to register the required validator in your set.